# Can't install vlc and other software : packages not coming from authenticated sources

Tags: 11.10, installation, vlc

After installing Ubuntu 11.10 last week I couldn't install any mp3 or videoplayers such as vlc or any others. They show me something about a failure to install packages, and when I click on details I see this:

> `The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources: libdvdread4 libvlc5 libvlccore4 vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse`

Comment: I think your OS have gone out-of-support. Try to [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/311010/156684), should be useful...

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure your software sources are enabled for Restricted Extras and Multiverse.

Open the Software Centre from Unity then select *Edit -> Software Sources*.

In the dialogue box that opens ensure you have the following selected;

[image: Software Sources]

Once this is done close the box and search for VLC in the Software Centre, you will then be able to install it.

Comment: I have all that selected, and the problem still persist.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, open your terminal by simultaneously pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and do the following (one line, then another):

```
Sudo apt-get update.
sudo apt-get upgrade.
```

Restart your system after finish running the above instructions.

- Click on Software Center on your launcher and type VLC on the search
  bar (if you couldn't find it among the items list). Click on the
  VLC icon and locate the <kbd>Install</kbd> button to install it.
- Go to your Dash Home and search for VLC. Click to test if it is
  working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

and answer `Yes` to the question.