# The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources

Tags: 12.04

× 5207

The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.

mplayer-gui mplayer-skins

from the ubuntu software center

I could not watch any .AVI without it, and rest of the software also require some packages to watch .AVI which is impossible to get?

thanks in nadvance

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you clarify a bit what you're asking, are you asking how to install the package you've cited? Or how to add non-authenticated sources? This would greatly help people trying to give you an answer.

Comment: your answer is probably here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73239/cant-install-vlc-and-other-software-packages-not-coming-from-authenticated-so?rq=1

Comment: This linke may have your answer:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/171144/update-manager-wont-install-from-un-authenticated-sources/171148#171148